# C++ Speeding up multiple substr() or equivalent function calls for parsing of a large string

Tags: c++, string, performance, data-structures, substr

I am trying to parse large strings that I have loaded into memory from a file. I am parsing DNA sequences (stored as string) with a sliding window of variable length. The problem is that the strings are so large that it takes a very long time to iterate through them. I don't know if it is even possible but is it possible to speed this up somehow?

I mean I expected I/O to dominate my application so I shift my line by line reading to reading the whole file into memory at once, but after testing my code I found it spends most of the time in a loop like this:

```
size_t currentCharNumber = 0;
int16_t windowSize = 50;
//seq is a string of length 249250621
while(seq.length() - currentLinePos < windowSize)
{
   string temp = seq.substr(currentLinePos, windowSize);
   //do stuff to temp
   ++currentLinePos;
}
```

It only take seconds for loading the sequence into memory from a file but takes ~30 mins to parse the sequence (even after commenting out the processing below the substr() call). Is there something I'm missing that is adding a lot of overhead or is it probably due to the size of my data?

Would it be helpful to mention that I can ignore substrings with characters other that ATCG? I mean I do this filtering in my code but only after I get the strings from substr.

This is my first time posting, and my C++ is a little rusty. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `substr` related to `std::string::substr`? Perhaps you meant `seq.substr(...)`?

Comment: Shouldn't `currentLinePos` be incremented by `windowSize` instead of just 1? Or do you mean `currentCharNumber`?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us the bigger context so you could improve the algorithm to avoid using `substr` at all.

Comment: @eq- Sorry that is what I should have put. Fixed.

Comment: @sonicwave I actually want every partial sequence, potentially having n - windowSize unique strings

Comment: @Nobody - I'm not sure if this is what you mean: Read FASTA file -> use sliding window to retrieve subsequences -> Convert strings to uppercase and remove sequences with non ATCG characters -> other downstream processing

Comment: String in C++ use an array of char or wchar, so you can consider working with char array to avoid the object construction and destruction initiated by the String.subtr() function.  String.str() function returns the char arrayOfChar[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider switching from using a `string` to hold your sliding window to using a `std::deque<char>`.  The `deque` type is optimized for inserting and removing values at either end, and is therefore a good candidate here.  You can start by loading the first 50 characters into the `deque`, and then can adjust your loop like this:

```
/* Initialize the window to the first windowSize characters. */
std::deque<char> window(seq.begin(), seq.begin() + windowSize);

/* Repeatedly process each window. */
for (size_t i = windowSize; i < seq.length(); ++i) {
    /* Do something to window */

    /* Drop the first character from the window, then add the next character
     * of the sequence.
     */
    window.pop_front();
    window.push_back(seq[i]);     
}
```

This makes the time to construct each window O(1) instead of O(k), where `k` is the number of characters in the window.  This could dramatically decrease the runtime, since the number of characters in your window is pretty large.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've used this and it a lot faster maybe a ~60% speedup overall. But everything downstream expects a string. I just had to change everything downstream. I have yet to try the two pointers method others have stated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can delimit your sliding window by two pointers into the original string and work with that instead of copying the entire range into a separate string. If `std::string` construction is an overhead, avoid it.

You could also re-use the very same `std::string` instance every time (assuming the window size is constant), but it would still cost you a copy operation (which may be negligible for small window/length ratios, though).

Answer (score 3):

Calls to `std::string::substr` may result in excessive dynamic memory allocations and, at the very least, copying buffers around. Often you can reduce the need to `substr` by altering your algorithm to use string-deliminating iterators instead.